# A computer window "pops" vs "pops up"

Tags: word-choice

In the context of computers and software, when a new windows appears on the screen, should we say:
a window pops
or
a window pops up

Based on my research, "pops up" is more correct, but can "pops" be used as well?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome!  I think this might have been better suited for the English Language Learner's forum. But, I did provide an answer below to help you to decode our idioms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popping is essentially a small explosion or noise from said explosion. For example, a bubble popping. It's not really the correct idiom for a computer window.

Popping up is an idiomatic representation of the suddenness of the appearance. A *pop up book* has parts that suddenly appear after being pushed out from their flat status.  This is the idiomatic representation that a pop up window is referencing.

Comment: Is this really within the spirit of ELU?

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - No. I voted to close. But, punting things to ELL doesn't mean that it cannot be answered. I answered out of netizenship rather than seeking points. Couldn't fit the answer in a comment.

Comment: Some have been known to run to three 'comments'. However, that too is not totally satisfactory.